# How to share a variable between two sub classes that implements runnable

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a main class and two subclasses, subClass1 and subClass2  that implements runnable...

I have run the two threads simultaneously

by calling

t1.start     // t1 for subclass1

t2.start      // t2 for subclass2

Now, I want t1 to run  till the t2 completes.

I can add a boolean flag within the method in subclass2 to recognize that the execution has been completed; 
Now I need to pass that information(boolean variable) to subclass1 to stop the execution of a set of codes from within it. [have used while(true) loop;]

so how can i create a common variable that can be accessed by both sub classes?

Can anybody please suggest me a solution for this?

Comment: show some code to explain what's going on. Is SubClass1 and SubClass2 inner classes of Main class? You could always pass the same reference of [AtomicBoolean](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html) to both subclasses.

Comment: The problem is a bit caused by your wording. You don't want to share a variable between classes, but you want to share an object between two instances. And the solution for that is pretty easy: construct the shared object. pass the shared object to the constructors of your runnable implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass an `AtomicBoolean` to the subclasses.

```
public class SubClass1 implements Runnable {
    private AtomicBoolean b;
    public SubClass1(AtomicBoolean b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(b.get()) {  // Assuming SubClass2 sets it to false when it's no longer running
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Implementing `SubClass2` is left as an exercise to the `OP`.

Comment: There's often a simple solution to a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If possible I'd recommend to avoid sharing mutable state in concurrent environment, but assuming you have one of those cases where it cannot be avoided you can try something like (adjust for your own needs):

```
class SharedState {
  public final Object mutex = new Object();
  public boolean variable;
}

class Subclass extends MyClass1 implements Runnable {
  private SharedState sharedState;

  public Subclass1(SharedState sharedState) {
    this.sharedState = sharedState;
  }

  // ...

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // ...
    synchronized(sharedState.mutex) {
      // access sharedState.variable
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

Basically create `SharedState` outside and inject into your subclasses on creation (or create it within one of them, retrieve and inject into another, whatever). Then use that shared variable remembering all you know about trickiness of shared state.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. :)